# Convert Dahon Mariner D7 to belt drive and internal hub?

Tags: folding-bicycle, belt-drive

Is it feasible to convert a Dahon Mariner D7 to use a belt drive and an internal 7 speed hub? Any ballpark estimates for cost of parts?

I ask because I am rehabilitating my Dahon sailing bike of 15 years and want to eliminate the mess of a chain.

I understand that it would require a Split Belt Drive and that adding an internal hub might be challenging.

Comment: There are belt systems with split belt and tensioner which should work: https://www.bikeradar.com/news/add-a-belt-drive-to-any-bike-with-veers-belt-drive Internal Gear hubs (e.g. Shimano’s Alfine 8) should also be compatible. I think the biggest problem with belt drives can be insufficient stiffness of the frame.

Answer (score 2):

Alright Doc.

There doesn't appear to be any way to tension a chain or belt on the D7, so it's purely derailleur and chain only.

You could consider using wax based chain lubricants on a new chain to minimise mess.